# A ball is dropped from a height of 1m above the ground.What will be the instantaneous speed of the ball when it is exactly at 1/2 mark?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, calculus, free-fall

I saw this question in this video [Instantaneous speed (differentiation) by Don't Memorize](https://youtu.be/UKrrX47_kmg?list=PLmdFyQYShrjd4Qn42rcBeFvF6Qs-b6e-L)
In the video, the instantaneous speed of the ball is given as 100cm/sec which is equal to 1m/sec but when I tried calculating using the $v=√(2gh)$ but the answer I got was = √9.8 which is approximately equal to √10m/s which is equal to 316cm/sec or 3.16m/sec. What is wrong with my calculations and why do we need calculus to solve the problem, why can't it be done using $v=√(2gh)$?

Answer (score 1):

> *What is wrong with my calculations and why do we need calculus to
> solve the problem, why can't it be done using $v=\sqrt{2gh}$?*

We need calculus because the velocity changes *all the time*. Quite literally $v$ is a function of time:

$$v(t)=f(t)$$

**Calculus deals with dynamic problems, where things (usually) change with time (as is the case here).**

In Newtonian physics we define the acceleration $a$ as (for one dimensional problems):
$$a=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{1}$$

i.o.w. the acceleration is the derivative of velocity w.r.t. time.

We can re-write $(1)$ as:

$$\mathrm{d}v=a\mathrm{d}t$$

In your problem $a$ is constant and equal to $g$, so:

$$\mathrm{d}v=g\mathrm{d}t$$

A process called *integration* then allows to calculate $v(t)$:

$$\int_0^{v(t)}\mathrm{d}v=\int_0^t g\mathrm{d}t$$

or:

$$v(t)=gt\tag{2}$$

Newtonian physics also tells us that:

$$v(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{1}$$

where $y$ is the vertical distance travelled (aka 'displacement'). Re-write as:

$$\mathrm{d}y=v(t)\mathrm{d}t=gt\mathrm{d}t$$

Again using integration:

$$\int_0^y\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^tgt\mathrm{d}t$$

or:

$$y=\frac12 gt^2\tag{3}$$

Use $(3)$ to find $t$ for a given $y$, then insert that value into $(2)$ to find the instantaneous velocity at that point.

---

[And here's a basic and very step-by-step webinar on Calculus of mine](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532#pid441089).

Comment: But we know that at height = 50cm, PE =KE so we can write it as mgh=1/2mv^2  this implies v = sqrt (2gh) so at ht = 0.5m, if we take acceleration due to gravity to be 10m/s^2, then we will get v= sqrt(10) m/s so in that way, the velocity at that instant will be 316cm/sec. We do not know the time the ball takes to cover half the distance as the speed is increasing and is not constant so we cannot calculate speed using that formula. We can calculate time though once we derive it as v= sqrt(2gh) right?

Comment: If you do all this, then you get the equation $v = \sqrt{2gh}$ that the OP started out with. So, yes, you need calculus to derive that formula. But once you have it, you should be able to use it to calculate.